Does Mem stats in htop includes allocated memory for Virtual machines?
I have several Virtual machines running on my ubuntu machine. These virtual machines are created using cockpit interface. The question is "When I see output of htop command, the "Mem" section includes the allocated memory of virtual machines as used or it shows the utilized memory of Virtual machines as used"
